# Expanding an expression for small values of a parameter

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I have a probability generating function

$$ G(z) = \Bigg(\frac{ 1-2d + \sqrt{1-4d(1-d)z}}{2(1-2d)}\Bigg)^{\frac{1-2d}{d^2}\kappa}\
 \Bigg(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4d(1-d)z}}{2dz}\Bigg)^{\frac{\kappa}{d^2}}$$

and I'd like to expand this for $d\rightarrow 0$. This expansion should retain the property $G(1)=1$.

My attempt was to use 
$$ \sqrt{1-4d(1-d)z} \approx 1-2dz$$
within both numerators of this expression,
and this obtains
$$G(z) \approx \Bigg(\frac{1-\frac{d}{1-d}z}{1-\frac{d}{1-d}}\Bigg)^{\frac{1-2d}{d^2}\kappa}. $$

However, I do not know if this is valid, since I neglected terms of $O(d^2)$ in the two terms, while I kept terms of $O(1/d^2$) in the exponent...

Is there some better way to do this limit $d\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: $G(z)=e^{\kappa  (z-1)} \left(1+d \kappa  \left(z^2-1\right)\right)+\mathcal O(d^2)$.

Comment: I believe that, since this limit shows a Poisson pgf as $d\rightarrow 0$, but how do you get the exponential factor? I was also hoping to show a transition from its full form to NegBin and progressively Poisson as $d$ gets smaller. Not sure if that's buried in the structure of $G$.